Laravel 9 Bug? Changing config/mail.markdown.theme does not work. Still loads default from vendor published folder
So editing the config/mail.php during launch time to let each user have their own mail template:
 Config::set('mail.markdown',[
        [
            'theme' => 'domain.com',

            'paths' => [
                resource_path('views/mail/template/domain.com'),
            ],
        ]
    ]);

While the views are loaded from the new path, the theme is still not only loading defaul.css but it is also loading it from the default path:
/vendor/mail/template/default.css
Can't imagine after so many versions laravel did not catch this, or am I missing something?
Update: I  was able to very least change the default.css but still inside the vendor folder, I had to set my mailable class $mail->theme='mytheme';

Personally have not used markdown for emails, but maybe the base of your email template uses the default.css?

From laravel docs, markdown will create a default CSS.:

After exporting the components, the
resources/views/vendor/mail/html/themes directory will contain a
default.css file. You may customize the CSS in this file and your
styles will automatically be converted to inline CSS styles within the
HTML representations of your Markdown mail messages.
If you would like to build an entirely new theme for Laravel's
Markdown components, you may place a CSS file within the html/themes
directory. After naming and saving your CSS file, update the theme
option of your application's config/mail.php configuration file to
match the name of your new theme.


yeah I read that too. It doesn't work as expected that is what I am saying. It will not load the custom if the layout is changed from the path specified
